# How can I export images from a postgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have a simple data table.

Schemas>resources>tables>image_data contains the columns

```
image_id(integer) raw_data(bytea)
```

How can I export this data to files named based on the image_id? Once I figure that out I want to use the image_id to name the files based on a reference in another table.

So far I've got this:

```
SELECT image_id, encode(raw_data, 'hex')
  FROM resources.image_data;
```

It generates a csv with all the images as HEX, but I don't know what to do with it.

Data-sample:

```
"image_id";"encode"
166;"89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d49484452000001e0000003160806000000298 ..."
```

Comment: The recent versions of Postgresql have the possibility of doing `copy` to a program, so you could write a shell or a program to read the line and write the file.

Comment: Are you interested in a PHP solution?